# There is an issue with white space when using an iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have an API app on my website which is using iframe. The main problem is that there is a white space which is impossible to cover through CSS.

I tried every css command so it seems to me like this is only possible to fix through javascript.

The screenshot that shows this issue:
[preview 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZEau.jpg)

When I set the height to 100% this will happen:
[height 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqTz1.jpg)

The usage of iframe looks like this:
[iframe code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1v9i.jpg)

The iframe loads a HTML page. I tried to set height to auto or 100% and other responsive commands but without success.
[responsive design settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtRmF.jpg)

Comment: iframe is a replaced element , and likely inherits a display:inline-block . reset display to block, and that white-space should be gone. You may also reset vertical-align to top or bottom. default is baseline , so with that gap below it :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.